# Merge Sort and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

Hi so im implementing a merge sort on an array with Objects of type person. Now im thinking theoretical here and i want advice on a non tedious approach as i realised my approach seems impractical.

So i have an array and i want to first merge sort the Surname in alphabetical order
which i have done but then i want to split the array again and merge for each letter (e.g. A) the first name. So for example my array would look like:

```
BRUCE WAYNE
JIM MORRIS
ALBERT EINSTEIN 
ADAM BILL
```

So the first merge is easy it would use the surname and merge:

```
ADAM BILL
ALBERT EINSTEIN
JIM MORRIS
BRUCE WAYNE
```

Then what i want to do is for every letter say for instance all the surnames with A i want to group into an array and do another merge with the first name
so like adam bill would go to an array with all the surnames that start with b and then would be merged in alphabetical order according to his first name. 
Now i cant figure out how im going to do this if there are 26 letters in the alphabet it seems pretty tedious to do 26 arrays. Can anyone help me figure out how i could do this with a modular design ?

I have a file with hundreds of names

Comment: Why do you want to sort the individual subarrays again when you can just compare surname and firstname at once. Write a comparator that compares either the complete string (last name has to come before firstname as in your example) alphabetically or compare the last name first and if it equals another last name, return the comparision of the first names.

Comment: my surname and first name are split so i should create something like  if (((A[ii].getSurname().compareTo(A[jj].getSurname())<0) || (A[ii].getSurname().compareTo(A[jj].getSurname()) == 0))  && ((A[ii].getname().compareTo(A[jj].getname())<0) || (A[ii].getname().compareTo(A[jj].getname()) == 0)) ) @Glains   (This is an if statement that does the merge sort so if i compare both surname & name like this will it work according to what you said)

Comment: It is preferable to use lists instead of arrays. You can group by the first letter either in List<List<YourPerson>> or in Map<String, List<YourPerson>>.

Comment: i found using a list to hard when doing a merge sort @Ilya

Comment: Why? myArray[i] equals myArrayList.get(i) and myArray.length equals myArrayList.size()

Comment: oh we arent allowed to use arraylists i thought you meant a linked list because i created my own linked list and tried implementing that with a merge and it did not go so well @Ilya

Comment: Hey does my comment at the top with the if statement look right?? @Ilya like does it theoretically sound right ?